# VPN接続不安定

Tags: ios, windows, vpn

ここで質問することでは、ないかもしれませんが、Yahoo知恵袋では、ちょっとむりそうなので、質問させていただきます。

ネット環境：ドコモ光
プロバイダ：OCNファミリー
VPNサーバ：Windows10Pro、最新SoftEther VPN
CPU:Intel Xeon E3 1231 v3@3.4GHz Mem:24G

Client:iPhone8（iOS14.4）、OpenVPN Connect
です。

VPNの接続が不安定です。

ネット記事で、VPNのクライアント側が不安定な場合ためしてみたら？というのがあり、

iPhone8側のovpn設定ファイルで

mssfix 1300

を設定してみましたが、安定しません。

サーバ側アンチウィルス対策ソフトで、SoftEtherをスキャン例外にして、iPhone側もウィルス対策ソフトをアンインストールしました。

Windows10マシンのUSB-HDDをVLCでSMB接続しようとしても、ユーザー認証の画面にすらならず、蹴られます。

やはり、回線、VPNサーバがしょぼいせいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

iPhoneの標準のVPNにしたら、安定しました。

ちゃんと、VPNで接続した、DLNAサーバを参照でき、動画が、再生できました